# Style Certain Table Rows from Database Query Set Data with CSS

Tags: php, css, mysql, html-table

I have a set of data in a MySQL database. I have a table created from these data using PHP loops. I want to style certain rows in certain ways. For example, the data fetched from the database are in groups of 2, 3, 4, 5 rows. There are a about 25 rows of data and I'd like to style each group a bit differently, e.g., add color to row sub heading...

I built this out and didn't quite take into consideration that this styling was necessary. The client wants this styling and now I'm trying to figure out how to make it.

Here is an image from Excel with the kind of thing I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

I could just hand write the HTML and then style it but the code is much cleaner and tighter when using the PHP loops. Also, if I can figure this out, I could use this as a model and template for other scenarios where I need to style certain parts of a table from more data.

Here is the PHP snippet:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>hd1</th>
        <th>hd2</th>
        <th>hd3</th>
    </tr>

    <?php

    $mysqli = <connect to db is fine>;

    $query = 'SELECT a, b, c from t1';

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $query)) {
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $a, $b, $c);

        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $a . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $b . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $c . '</td>'; 
            echo '</tr>';       
        }
    }

    ?>

</table>
```

Comment: Please provide your PHP code

Comment: It's very straight forward. It's a boilerplate PHP `while` loop. nothing fancy...  I'll add snippets.

Comment: do you want to stylish rows based on cell's content ?

Comment: How does your MySQL table look like? Is there any way of knowing when to apply a certain style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this part of code add a class for your sub-headings :

```
$subheadingsContent = array("a", "sub heading", "cell data");

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {


    if(in_array($a, $subheadingsContent)) echo '<tr class="subheading">';

    echo '<td>' . $a . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $b . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $c . '</td>'; 
    echo '</tr>';       
}
```

And add class in your css file foreach element , for the first , the second , third .... :

```
 .subheading:nth-child(1){background-color:blue;}
 .subheading:nth-child(2){background-color:orange;}
 .subheading:nth-child(3){background-color:gray;}
```

Comment: I ended up using specific tests and unique classes and this worked great - thanks a bunch.

Comment: @nicorellius i added array of values , and you check if $a is in this array.

Answer (score 0):

For each different group of rows you could add a class to style each one in your php. Then in your css style according to each class.

For example give your heading row a class of `blueHeading` and then in your css just set the `background-color` attribute to be blue.

This is basically what the html class attribute is for.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the name of the subheading in the loop and color the td's background

```
if($subheading == 'foo') {
    echo '<td class="foo">';
}
```